# Visualization of a ArangoDB graph, sigma.js?

Tags: javascript, arangodb, sigma.js

I am working with ArangoDb and after i finally got my data into the database I now want to visualize my graph. The built-in visualization is sadly not enough for me since I need to do things like highlighting nodes and change the thickness of edges etc.

So I am looking for a way to visualize a graph that is able to do such things. I found Sigma.js which seems to be what I need, but is there a (easy, since I am pretty inexperienced) way to use Sigma.js with an ArangoDb graph?

Comment: You would probably write a [foxx-service](https://docs.arangodb.com/Foxx/index.html) to [select the graph from ArangoDB using AQL](https://docs.arangodb.com/Graphs/index.html) and give you the graph representation that sigma.js needs.

Comment: Thank you, ill have a look into this!

Comment: Did you have any success on this? can we mark it resolved?

Answer (score 3):

There are several javascript graph visualisation solutions in the field, one of them is Sigma.js.

You can do arbitrary queries on ArangoDB and format the structures to your needs; However there is no shrink wrap solution for this.

Other solutions successfully use d3.js.

I.e. the ArangoDB Graph viewer.
In [this question mchacki successfully demonstrate how to query ArangoDB for visualisation with d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855799/getting-data-for-d3-from-arangodb-using-aql-or-arangojs).