# Arango single tree response using AQL only

Tags: d3.js, arangodb, aql

I have found several questions that are similar but no solution worked as needed, or used internal functions. This is the most relevant one:
[Getting data for d3 from ArangoDB using AQL (or arangojs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855799/getting-data-for-d3-from-arangodb-using-aql-or-arangojs)

I'm unable to understand how to return a single response with a tree structure of parent + children. Something that D3 can understand. Whatever I do, beyond the first iteration, everything is a mess. I have tried MERGE and MERGE_RECURSIVE but it just did not work as I thought of. 
I'm clueless to how I can make it to work. I'm used to Neo4J and for some reason this one is just hard for me to understand.

Any help will do,
Thanks,
DD.

Comment: I found a simple solution. I'm just using AQL to get a flat list of results and their edges. After that, I just sort it as I need on my code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution. I'm just using AQL to get a flat list of results and their edges. After that, I just sort it as I need on my code

Comment: If you can provide what your query looks like, it might be possible to show you how to sort the data in the AQL. I've done queries before pulling data to be used by nvd3 charts and was able to do most of the sorting and parsing in AQL, so the code has to do almost nothing extra to the result.